# cURL - Unknown SSL protocol error with TLS1 and AES_128_CBC

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm trying to get a cURL command to work and have been unable to figure out the correct syntax. Everything I've tried (listed below) results in an "Unknown SSL protocol error".

When I make the request in Chrome 42 I get a 200 response with the expected plaintext body "beat". There is a warning, however, and Chrome shows that the request is made using TLS 1.0 and the connection is encrypted using AES_128_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA for key exchange.

Given this information, I would like to be able to make a request to the same URL using cURL and get the response "beat".

[image: Requested with Chrome]

The certificates I am trying to pass to cURL were exported from Keychain into both the .pem and .cer formats.

Here's what I have tried. Every one of these commands has failed with the same message "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to cxdev.sircon.com:-9824".

```
curl --trace - --ciphers ALL --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -k -v -1 -4 https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -k -v -1 https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -k -v https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --cacert ./sircon.pem https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --ciphers ALL --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --tlsv1 --cacert ./sircon.pem https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --tlsv1 --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --tlsv1 --ciphers AES128 --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --tlsv1 --ciphers AES128-SHA --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v --tlsv1 --ciphers ALL --cacert sircon.cer https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v -1 https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
curl -v https://cxdev.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/AutomatedProcessing/rest/ekg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new internal CA and certificate fixed the issue. Using TLS 1.0 and encrypting the connection using AES_256_CBC with SHA1 for message authentication and ECDHE_RSA, I was able to get Chrome to show a nice green lock icon when accessing the URL and every single one of the `curl` commands that I posted in my question are now able to successfully retrieve the resource.